# Magento emails not sending out at all

Tags: php, database, magento, smtp, gmail

Our Magento hasn't never sent out emails for the last few months, such as order confirmations and password resets. The cron is running fine and i'm using AOE Scheduler to check it. It has a heartbeat and is firing every 5 minutes.

I've been advised its our email server that is the culprit, so have installed SMTP pro and created a new gmail account, adding these credentials to Magento, to run through gmail.

Can anyone else advise anything else to try, they're still not sending.

Added SMTP self test results:

```
SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: support@ourcompany.zendesk.com from: myemail@gmail.com. Unable to send test email.
Exception message was: Incorrect authentication data 
Please check the user guide for frequent error messages and their solutions.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.
Required database tables exist.
Testing failed, please review the reported problems and if you need further help visit the support page or contact me via support@aschroder.com for support.
```

Tried to disable Mandrill - don't know if that is the conflict...

Comment: core_email_queue in the database is always empty, should it be?

Comment: Okay so the queue does have some records in....but not sending them out.

Comment: Keep in mind, gmail has sending limits.

Comment: did you run "self test" using smtp extension, did it gave any error ?

Comment: @henry i've just moved it to gmail and it isnt sending anything at all.

Comment: @jord49 I know, I can't help you with Magento, but I just wanted to alert you to your next issue your going to face, when you get it working.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe Have added results to this question. Can you see anything that would result in no emails sending at all?

Comment: you can do quick search in google regarding those error lines. better now itself send one mail to `support@aschroder.com`